# Design a normalized database for a bus ticketing system. Passengers travel from a various source places to various destination places

Tags: database-design, rdbms

I have an interesting database design problem that I formulated while travelling by a bus, coming back from my home.

Design a normalized database for a bus ticketing system (not reservation system). In each trip, the conductor of the bus will give tickets to its passengers after collecting fare from them. Passengers travel from a various source places to various destination places.

The system must be able to give a report of the places for which the number of passengers was more than 2.

Suppose the stops for the bus are L1,L2, L3 and L4
Suppose passenger P1 travels from L1 to L4.  P2 travels from L2 to L4. P3 travels from L3 to L4.

The report should list only (L3-L4) for which it has more than 2 travelers.

Can you please help me to solve the following problems

1)  Design a normalized database

2)  Write a query for the report

3)  Is there any site that gives these kinds of interesting database design questions and answers?

Comment: > 3) Is there any site that gives these kinds of interesting database design questions...
I'm guessing the answer to that is "your class".

Comment: This looks like a task for a homework or interview assignment. "design a normalized database", "write a query", "the report should list" are all criteria for something of this nature and not something I would generally write out if I was asking for help regarding a design idea I thought up in my head for fun.

Comment: Sounds like an assignment to me, not that difficult i would suggest having a go and posting your stuff if you need help on speciifc points ;-)

Comment: Definitely homework question.

Comment: For most part, this forum is great. But it is pathetic that many of my questions are doubted as homework probelms. I am a software professional with 3 years of experience. I tried with the design when I travelled in an overloaded bus, yesterday.   The problem seems to interesting and challenging to me with my reporting requirement. Beleive me if you can. .. I am sure I can reach an answer. But I am lokking for other answers as well.

Comment: This reminds me of liveness analysis from compiler class.

Answer (score 1):

DataBase Design:

```
Location Table

 - LocationID  (p)
 - LocationName

TravelTable 

 - TravelID  (p)
 - PassengerID
 - LocationFrom (F) - (Location - LocationID)
 - LocationTo  (F) - (Location - LocationID)

PassengerTable

 - PassengerID (p)
 - PassengerName
```

Sites from where you get proper answer:

- https://blog.sqlauthority.com/
- https://www.sqlservercentral.com/

Comment: Thanks. One key point. How do you decide the order of locations; like L3 is after L2?

Comment: Because a bus travels in a straight line and l3 comes after l2.  Unless you're going back in which case l3 comes before l2.  Or you're teleporting in which case l1 comes after l3 and l2 comes before l4.

Comment: My point here is, we should not be using the order of records in Location table as the order of actual location.

Comment: you can decide order of the location form locationId and or by adding one more column LocationOrder in location table

Answer (score 0):

The key table would be:

trip (trip_id, passenger_id, start_location_id, end_location_id)

You might have a location table with information about the stops.

Then the query would simply be

```
select start_location_id, end_location_id, count(*)
from trip
group by start_location_id, end_location_id
having count(*)>=2
```

**Edit**

Per comment below, maybe I'm misunderstanding the requirement. Are you trying to find TRIPS that have more than 2 passengers, or LOCATIONS that have more than 2 passengers, or what? That is, if we have trips (Al, L1, L2), (Betty, L1, L2), (Carl, L1, L3), (Donna, L2, L4), should the output be:

```
L1, L2, 2
```

(and that's all)?

Or should it be

```
L1, 3
L2, 3
```

I believe my query above would give the first result. If you're looking for the second result, it would be:

```
select location, sum(visits)
from
(
select start_location_id as location, count(*) as visits
from trip
union
select end_location_id as location, count(*) as visits
from trip
)
group by location
having sum(visits)>=2
order by location
```

As you're adding together counts for two different columns, I don't see any way to avoid using the union and an inner query.

Arguably, a different schema would make this query a whole lot easier, namely, instead of trip have trip_stop:

trip_stop (passenger_id, location_id, stop_number)

where stop_number is, say, 1 for start location and 2 for end location.

Now that I think about it, this is really better, as it eliminates having two fields that represent the same idea, as well as making it easy to expand to having trips with multiple stops.

Then the query simply becomes

```
select location_id, count(*)
from trip_stop
group by location_id
having count(*)>=2
order by location_id
```

Comment: I don't think this will meet the requirement. When you group by using start location and end location, each one of them will make separate group. No records will be selected. (TripID PassID StartLoc EndLoc) (1 P1 L1 L4) (1 P2 L2 L4) (1 P3 L3 L4)

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of liveness analysis from compiler class.  There the goal is to find out which variables are in use at the same time so register allocation is more efficient.  The other answers cover the database part pretty well. For the algorithm on finding which x (trip, location) have multiple passengers, read up on liveness analysis and linear scan.